# Compute two original colors from mixed color with given hues

Tags: colors, hsv

I'm writing a program which re-colorizes images into a given color scheme of two given colors.

I have a color C with hue 79, saturation 47 and value 67. I know that this color was mixed by two colors A and B. Hue of A is 50, hue of B is 198. Is it possible to compute saturation and value for A and B?

In general: Is there an algorithm for computing saturation and value of colors A and B if color C is a mixture of A and B, hues of A, B and C are known and saturation/value of C is known?

(Expected results, if such an algorithm existed:

A: saturation 100, value: 95

B: saturation 73, value: 70

)

Comment: But in general, I think the answer is "no".  You're solving a system of three equations, with four unknowns.

Comment: Hmm I don't know much about colors. Paint.net says blending mode "normal"...

Comment: Well, I know that the resulting color C is 50% of color A and 50% of color B which also counts as information when solving the equations

Comment: Maybe.  You have Ch = fh(Ah, As, Av, Bh, Bs, Bv), Cs = fs(Ah, As, Av, Bh, Bs, Bv), Cv = fv(Ah, As, Av, Bh, Bs, Bv) (where the f are three functions).  In general, you can't solve those for four unknowns.

Comment: You are right. Why didn't you answer the question via normal "Answer" button?